# Pass stdin to Command without interfering with user stdin

Tags: rust

I've been having trouble sort of succinctly describing what I'm tying to accomplish, but what I'm attempting to do is write a program that will execute other programs/scripts as plugins, and during that execution, facilitate communication between my program and the other program/script for various requests (like asking for a userlist, for example). However, if these other programs/scripts need to communicate with the end user, I'd also like to not get in the way of that. I explored some other means of doing this (like dbus, an http api, a different file handle, etc), and all those options are either too heavy a solution for what I'm trying to do, or I didn't have much success in implementing (as is the case of the last idea), and just using normal STDIN/STDOUT seems like the cleanest path forward.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
let mut child = Command::new("test.pl")
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failed to spawn child process");

let mut stdin = child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();

writeln!(&mut stdin, "Hey, testing!").unwrap();

let stdout = child.stdout.as_mut().unwrap();
let stdout_reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
let stdout_lines = stdout_reader.lines();

for line in stdout_lines {
    match line.unwrap().as_str() {
        "member_list" => {
            println!("Here's a member list");
            let mlist = cluster::members_list()?;
            for (member, port) in mlist.iter() {
                writeln!(&mut stdin, "{}:{}", member, port);
            }
        }
        e => {
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    };
}

child.wait().unwrap();
```

This works well with communication between my program and the other, passing STDOUT to the user if it doesn't match any of the keywords expected for communication. However, I can't think of a way of being able to pass information to STDIN of the other program without getting in the way of the other program requesting input from the user (such as if the program needs to ask the user, not my program, for input). I tried a silly usage of `drop(stdin);` and redeclaring stdin later on, which of course didn't work due to scope issues.

I'm really trying to avoid acting as an intermediary for STDIN since that seems like it would be terribly messy. I would appreciate any insight into how I might be able to accomplish this. I'm also open to other ideas on facilitating this communication other than through STDIN/STDOUT.

Thanks all!

Comment: If stdin is connected to a pipe to the parent process, then stdin isn't connected to the terminal. You can't have both there. Using different file descriptors for the pipe should work, but it's probably easier to use Unix domain sockets instead. See e.g. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/net/struct.UnixListener.html

Comment: Hmm, a socket is the right general idea, but still feels like a heavy solution for what I'm trying to do, which is spawn a short-lived communication channel between my program and another. Having to plop down a socket file and say "talk to me through here" seems like too much if I could just talk directly, like through another file descriptor. It's entirely probable I wasn't implementing that correctly. Do you think you could provide an example of how to set up something like what I'm doing over, say, file descriptor 3? @SvenMarnach

Comment: You could use a [`pipe`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.23.0/nix/unistd/fn.pipe.html) instead, but I'm pretty sure you'd need to drop down to almost C-level API for that. The end result would be very similar to the mechanism used to connect stdin/stdout, except that on a separate fd.

Comment: @AdamV As I said, a pair of anonymous pipes will work as well, but you will have to manually make sure to create both pipes and close one end of each pipe in both the parent and the child process. Overall, you'll have to figure out a lot of low-level code, whereas talking via a Unix domain socket is completely covered by the standard library. And the socket "file" is just a name for the the socket – the communication itself is just as "direct" as it is with pipes. Note that for two-way communication with pipes, you woudln't have one file descriptor, but four (two pipes with two ends each).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [anonymous pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe). In Linux, at a high level, that would look like this:

- Your process creates the pipe using the [`pipe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) system call, which returns a pair of FDs, one for the reading end of the pipe and the other for the writing end
- Your process then forks. In the child subprocess, you then call `exec` to start the process you want to run, passing it one of the FDs as a command line argument
- The new program takes the FD and uses it to communicate with the parent process.
- Both the parent and child process should take care to close the FDs representing the half of the connection they are not using.

You can do this in rust - the needed system calls are exposed in the libc crate, or by the more rust-friendly [nix crate](https://docs.rs/nix/0.23.0/nix/unistd/fn.pipe2.html).

I also stumbled across the [`interprocess`](https://docs.rs/interprocess/1.1.1/interprocess/unnamed_pipe/index.html) crate which provides an abstraction over these low level calls.

These newly created FDs are completely independant of the stdin / stdout / stderr of the process.

If bidirectional communication is required you could use two such pipes (one for each direction) - however in that case it is probably easier to use an anonymous socket, which you create using the [`socketpair`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) system call. This works in a similar fashion to the pipe, returning a pair of FDs - except that in this case the FDs are bi-directional. Again, [`libc`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.104/libc/fn.socketpair.html) and [`nix`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.23.0/nix/sys/socket/fn.socketpair.html) expose this system call.